# Postgres select where specific array in enum array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this example:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.animals
(
  name character varying(64),
  whitelist animal_whitelist[]
)
```

Custom enum type animal_whitelist:

```
CREATE TYPE public.animal_whitelist AS ENUM
  ('dog',
  'cat',
  'bird');
```

How can I select specifically to the white list.

In pseudo code this is what I would like to select.

- Any rows where the `animal_whitelist` equals `dog`
- Any rows where the `animal_whitelist` equals `dog` **and** `cat`
- Any rows where the `animal_whitelist` equals `dog` **or** `cat`
- Any rows where the `animal_whitelist` is **not** `dog`, `cat`, or `bird`

Comment: Start with the documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different things otherwise I wouldn't have posted here. It get's weird because it's an array of enums. Contains `@>` gets me close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please, check this [one](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1792e/14):

```
    insert into animals ("name", "whitelist") values ('bobic', array['dog']::animal_whitelist[]);
insert into animals ("name", "whitelist") values ('barsic', array['cat']::animal_whitelist[]);
insert into animals ("name", "whitelist") values ('pet', array['dog', 'cat', 'bird']::animal_whitelist[]);
insert into animals ("name") values ('jim');


-- Any rows where the animal_whitelist equals dog
select * from animals where  array['dog']::animal_whitelist[] = "whitelist" ;

-- Any rows where the animal_whitelist equals dog and cat
select * from animals where  array['dog', 'cat']::animal_whitelist[] = "whitelist" ;

-- Any rows where the animal_whitelist equals dog or cat
select * from animals where  array['dog', 'cat']::animal_whitelist[] <@ "whitelist" ;

-- Any rows where the animal_whitelist is not dog, cat, or bird
select * from animals where not array['dog', 'cat', 'bird']::animal_whitelist[] && "whitelist";
```

Comment: Both of our answers worked but since you provided better commenting and an online SQL tool I selected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out with some more experimentation

1. `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE whitelist @> ARRAY['dog'::whitelist]`
2. `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE whitelist @> ARRAY['dog'::whitelist, 'cat'::whitelist] AND NOT whitelist @> ARRAY['bird'::whitelist]`
3. `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE whitelist @> ARRAY['dog'::whitelist] OR whitelist @> ARRAY['cat'::whitelist]`
4. `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE NOT whitelist @> ARRAY['dog'::whitelist, 'cat'::whitelist, 'bird'::whitelist]`